# Webcam recognized but not functioning in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, webcam, tablet

I recently got a MSI WindPad 110W tablet PC. I installed Windows 8 Pro on it. The tablet has two webcams, one on each side (Facing the user and facing away from the user). Both are listed in Windows' Device Manager as "BisonCam, NB Pro". Using Windows' drivers I cannot get either camera to work. Both are enabled in Device Manager. I have tried the Windows "Camera" app and third party programs, all recognize the camera, but just display a black screen.

I have tried as a troubleshooting method, booting Ubuntu 12.10 and using cheese (webcam software) and both cameras work fine that way. Does anyone have suggestions on how to get them to work in Windows?

Comment: You need to provide drivers.  Contact MSI for assistance.

Comment: Googling your issue and looking around the Web, it seems that your cameras have been giving Windows users problems for at least 5 years. The most telling post explained how the Windows drivers supplied by Microsoft did not work at all. Yes, I know that's not very helpful. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it.

You have to enable location services in Control Panel > Location. If not turned on, this evidently disables all system sensors, including built-in cameras. After doing this, the Windows 8.1 camera app picks them up without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, that specific tablet PC Device is not designed to run windows 8, or at least, the driver is not compatible with 8. Either way, Windows is simply unable to use the device without the correct drivers for it.

It likely works in Ubuntu because that version of Ubuntu likely has a universal driver that is compatible with your PC's webcams. Windows, however, apparently doesn't have any such multi-device driver that Ubuntu has.

According to the driver download website for your product, the WindPad Cameras use a driver that comes with windows- This puzzles me as to why this driver seemingly doesn't operate on your computer.